# How to declare the Paho MQTT C++ in another c++ file?

Tags: c++, arm, embedded, paho

Below is my project structure,

```
root@user-VirtualBox:/home/user/octane_etk_sample-6.0.0.240# ls
bin                 include   paho.mqtt.c    speedway_embedded_example.cpp
cap                 lib       paho.mqtt.cpp  VERSION
cap_description.in  Makefile  SCMREV
```

I have the paho.mqtt.cpp package inside the project directory i.e.,octane_etk_sample-6.0.0.240 and I have installed all the steps which is mentioned in https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.cpp.

Now, I have included the MQTTAsync header file in speedway_embedded_example.cpp as like below,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "ltkcpp.h"
#include "impinj_ltkcpp.h"
#include "time.h"


#include "/home/user/octane_etk_sample-6.0.0.240/paho.mqtt.c/src/MQTTAsync.h"
```

After including the header file, I am trying to establish the MQTT client connection inside the public class,

```
void
CMyApplication::printOneTagReportData (
  CTagReportData *              pTagReportData)
{
   string address = "tcp://mqtt1.mindlogic.com:1883";
   cout << "OK\n" << address;


   mqtt::async_client cli(address, "", 120, "data-persist");
}
```

When I try to make a speedway_embedded_example file, I am getting below error,

```
root@user-VirtualBox:/home/mindlogic/octane_etk_sample-6.0.0.240# make
mkdir -p ./bin
g++ \
    -m32 -Wno-write-strings \
    -Iinclude \
    speedway_embedded_example.cpp \
    -Llib -lltkcpp_x86 -lltkcppimpinj_x86 -lxml2_x86 \
    -L/usr/bin -ldl -lssl -lcrypto \
    -o bin/speedwayr_x86
speedway_embedded_example.cpp: In member function ‘void CMyApplication::printOneTagReportData(LLRP::CTagReportData*)’:
speedway_embedded_example.cpp:1650:4: error: ‘mqtt’ has not been declared
    mqtt::async_client cli(address, "", 120, "data-persist");
```

Will anyone help me out to establish a client connection in the above scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You're including the C library, which doesn't have namespaces.

You (likely) want the C++ library.

https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.cpp

Or better yet, since you included the embedded tag, you may want to use

https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.embedded-c

which has embedded code for both C and C++. You should use the example code provided by the library you're using.

Comment: Sure, I will look into paho.mqtt.embedded-c